# Is there any difference between the 2D continuous and discrete Gabor filter when it comes to MATLAB implementation

Tags: image-processing, matlab, wavelet, gabor

I want to know the difference between the 2D continuous and discrete Gabor filter when it comes to Matlab implementation. I found many files related to 2D Gabor filter on Mathworks File Exchange but I am unable to find any file related to 2D continuous Gabor wavelet. I want to use continuous Gabor filter to enhance blood vessels in retinal images. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The CWT & DWT implementations differ in how they discretize the scale parameter used to stretch or shrink copies of the basic wavelet.

The finer grain scale parameter in the CWT can be useful for applications that require a very high fidelity signal analysis, for example, where localization of transients or precise characterizations of signal periodicities are critical.

Taken from [Continuous Wavelet Transform vs Discrete Wavelet Transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/76624) by [ruoho ruotsi](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/11372/ruoho-ruotsi).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are interested in the difference between the discrete wavelet transform and the continuous wavelet transform. Try looking up those topics.

Answer (score -1):

I came to know that technically there's no difference between the 2D discrete and Continuous Gabor filter when it comes to MATLAB every thing is discrete